# Securing web.config settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. We hired some remote developers to help us with the project.

The web.config file contains connection strings and app settings that we don't want to share with these remote developers. To work on our application, these developers remote into a development desktop that we control.

What is the best practice for securing sensitive information in web.config, so that developers can still run and debug application but not  read the sensitive info in web.config?

Comment: I recently faced something very similar to this. If your application is being housed on a central server where people remote in to it, you can do web.config encryption using the machine level keys using aspnet_regiis. [MSDN aspnet_regiis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).
It's worth noting though, that you can still get these values by calling them with WebConfigurationManager.

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose if we deal with something like securing an API key, then there is still no way to secure that key since the API expects it to be passed in a "clear" form, so a developer just needs to put a break point in the right place to see the key...

Comment: If you don't trust the developers, why did you hire them?

Comment: I don't think it's 100% possible to hide this information from the developers. You may be able to get really creative and create a library of utilities for the developers to use as .dll's, and try to hide those API interactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encrypting the `web.config` in a development environment is pointless. The only way to truely hide the information from the developers is not to give it to them in the first place.

1. You must ensure that your "remote development environment" is setup only to access a development database and is configured with other development settings only.
2. Don't check in any sensitive data (production passwords, etc) into your source control. You can achieve this by separating the information into [external `.config` files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx) so they are not checked into source control. **TIP:** [Ignore the file with the *actual* passwords](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755682/ASP-NET-MVC-Keep-Private-Settings-Out-of-Source-Co) and add another one with the same name and an extension such as `.config.example` that *is* checked in to give the developer instructions on how to setup the file on their local system (which is a helpful reminder regardless of *who* sets up the system from a clone of the source control repository).
3. Use a continuous integration server ([TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/), etc) to build sensitive information into the release workflow through **environment variables**. Many CI servers have the ability to [hide sensitive data from the UI](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Typed+Parameters#TypedParameters-AddingParameterSpecification). You can either practice automatic deployment via CI button-click so your developers don't have access to the sensitive data that is in the CI server, or give the deployment artifact(s) to a trusted team to install in production.

There is really no reason why a developer should even be given a chance to see sensitive production data such as passwords and private keys.

Answer (score 2):

Like `Ingenioushax` suggested, the standard way of encrypting sections of web.config is using aspnet_regiis. [Here is a tutorial](http://ryaremchuk.blogspot.com/2012/11/encrypting-and-decrypting-webconfig.html).

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying your application?

If you use a tool such as [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) - that only your onshore team have access to - you can use that to store any sensitive settings. These will get inserted into your configuration file during deployment.

In Octopus Deploy these are known as [configuration variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files#Configurationfiles-ConfigurationVariables).

This assumes that the sensitive settings are for environments *other* than ones that the developers will use themselves (Production and UAT, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can store config variables in environment variables and read them into the app at run time - this is better because each developer and environment can have their own configs that will never collide with others.

Comment: So, if I store a connection password in an Environment variable, what would prevent a not-trusted developer from seeing that variable? Like, in Powershell, it's get-childitem env:

Comment: this (and anything else in that matter) will not really work, the dev can debug, put break point, watch, etc. they have full control of the memory space.

Comment: so you're sharing a machine?

Comment: you can encrypt the strings? then put them in env vars